# Query multiple lists in different sites and display them like a OOTB list

Tags: content-query-web-part, query, content-search-web-part

I have different subsites which contain lists called "Articles".
On the root site I need to query these lists ("Articles") and display all them in a OOTB "list like" fashion.

What is the best way to do this?
Anyone has any ideas?
Is it better to use Content Query web part or Content Search Web part?
Or to built a custom web part?

Answer (score 0):

CQWP Is the best solution for what you are looking for.

If CQWP doesn't fits your requirement then you can still extend the CQWP on top of to that you can write you own custom Code.

Comment: CQWP uses xslt and it does not help you display data like OOTB list and I think it is much more difficult to manipulate it.